# Running main.py: (null), Unable to open main.py, abort

Tags: python, xcode, kivy

I try develop an simple kivy app for my tablet, but I have some problems with Xcode. Does someone know, what does this error mean?

I've tried adding librarys, reinstalling Xcode, updating Xcode.

```
2019-04-25 14:58:30.902305+0200 penproject[4549:99657] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
2019-04-25 14:58:31.188795+0200 penproject[4549:99657] [framework] CUIThemeStore: No theme registered with id=0
2019-04-25 14:58:31.778856+0200 penproject[4549:99657] Available orientation: KIVY_ORIENTATION=LandscapeLeft LandscapeRight Portrait PortraitUpsideDown
2019-04-25 14:58:31.779267+0200 penproject[4549:99657] PythonHome is: /Users/davidarchibald/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/6840F9A1-01A3-4C9B-88E4-F645482929B0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A34340B4-F2C5-450C-9F5E-ACD5F82AF3E9/penproject.app
2019-04-25 14:58:31.782511+0200 penproject[4549:99657] Initializing python
2019-04-25 14:58:31.962334+0200 penproject[4549:99657] Running main.py: (null)
2019-04-25 14:58:31.962547+0200 penproject[4549:99657] Unable to open main.py, abort.
2019-04-25 14:58:31.965485+0200 penproject[4549:99657] Leaving
```

Comment: Is your script named `main.py`? Are you trying to run on a simulator or on your actual tablet?

Comment: Yes it is. I am trying both, ipad and simulator. I have also tried change the path from documents to desktop and user. still the same error. And i can‘t find any information about it on the internet..

Comment: Have you tried redownloading kivy-ios from github? I haven't seen this error either, so I'm not sure exactly what might by causing this. Also, are you building python2 or python3 with the toolchain from kivy-ios?

Comment: Yes, I have tried redownloading. I am using python2 now, but last week I have tried on both, 2 and 3. Then I have read, that python3 has some issues with Kivy, so I deinstalled it.

Comment: Hi David, did you find out how to fix this issue? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

In the main.m file it said **#define MAIN_EXT @"pyc"** and there should be the problem.

I removed the "c" which make main.py accessible.

form:
#define MAIN_EXT @"pyc"

to:
#define MAIN_EXT @"py"

Then I could find the following code in main.m:

****** main.m line 77 ******

```
    // Search and start main.py
#define MAIN_EXT @"pyc"

    const char * prog = [
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourApp/main" ofType:MAIN_EXT] cStringUsingEncoding:
    NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved when I build by detaching the project folder from the build directory (main.py file needs to be in the project directory).